# A way to write decimal fractions like $1.333\dots$

Tags: notation, fractions

Sorry if my question sounds odd; I'm a typographer, not a mathematician. Is there a *better* way to write decimal fractions like $1.333\dots$ or $1.444\dots$?

By "better" I mean that

- it should be clear that the decimal point is followed by infinite series of only one digit (that is, it should be clear that we mean $1.33333333333333\dots$ and not something like $1.3333333333333341333\dots$)
- the notation should be compact. This is why writing these fraction like $4:3$ or $13:9$ is not a way to go for me.

Comment: Try $$1.33…=1.\bar 3$$

Comment: Thanks, Tyma. It seems your comment is the answer :-)

Comment: it is a [repeating decimal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).

Comment: I think $1.\dot{3}$ does also look good.

Comment: I’m not sure why $4:3$ is not compact. But you clearly want to represent the decimal representation, not the fractional one.

Comment: I always (for the last 50 years)  thought that $1.\bar3 $ is the standard notation. @Hermis, did you see your notation somewhere?

Comment: @markvs In my country, it's standard in high school textbooks :) I didn't know that the upper bar is standard.

Comment: @Hermis, $1. \bar3$ was standard in my previous country. I do not know what is standard in the USA.

Comment: @markvs Anyway the upper bar notation seems more efficient when there are two or more repeating digits.

Comment: @Hermis14: Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by simply putting a bar on top of the decimal digits that repeat, for example, $\frac{1}{7} = 0.142857142857142857...$ which you can write $0.\overline{142857}$.

It's even better to write fractions like $\frac{3}{44} = 0.06\overline{81}$ which have repeating digits that don't start immediately after the dot.

You can find some other ways to write fractions on [this website](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/fractions.html#section1.4) if you want (in section 1.4).